# Open/Save File Dialog That Works with Windows 64-bit

Tags: vbscript, openfiledialog

My open/save dialog box that used to work on windows XP no longer works on my Windows 7 64-bit. I have heard that 'MSComDlg.CommonDialog' is not compatible with 64-bit. Here is my old code:

```
' Sub to show open/save dialog
SUB OpenSave (varOpenSaveInputBox, varOpenSaveType, varOpenSaveFilter)   
   ' Create object
   SET objComDlg32 = CreateObject("MSComDlg.CommonDialog")
   ' Set memory buffer
   objComDlg32.MaxFileSize = 260
   ' Set filter
   objComDlg32.Filter = varOpenSaveFilter
   ' Show dialog 
   IF varOpenSaveType = 0 Then
      objComDlg32.ShowOpen
   ELSE
      objComDlg32.ShowSave
   End IF    
   ' Get filename from dialog
   strOpenSave = objComDlg32.FileName
   ' Check IF dialog is cancelled
   IF strOpenSave <> vbNullString Then
      ' Set to variable
      objOpenSave.SetContent strOpenSave, TRUE
   End If
END SUB
```

I would really appreciate if you be more specific with your answer rather than "Use this!". DLL and OCX is not really my strong suit. Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean 'no longer works' exactly? I thing it is not a problem of Win7 64-bit. What office edition do u have? U have to have developer edition.

Comment: what language? vba, vbscript and activex are all different technologies

Comment: @DanielDusek I'm not using it in office, I'm using it in QlikView. I need an openfile dialogue that works in win7 64-bit. if you know a replacement for 'MSComDlg.CommonDialog i would appreciate it.

Comment: @Sean Cheshire vbscript.

Comment: This is quite old question and you probably got an answer but for those who may have came accross looking for the same answer - the only 'generic' way would be to use BrowseForFolder method from Shell.Application (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Greg0ry, you should add your comment as an answer. It will be more visible to future visitors, and you will gain reputation if people think it's useful (as opposed to comments, which don't give reputation).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code, which I found somewhere on the internet (possibly even on StackOverflow. I don't remember exactly)

```
Function ChooseFile (ByVal initialDir, filter)

    dim shel, fso, tempdir, tempfile, powershellfile, powershellOutputFile,psScript, textFile
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    tempDir = shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")

    tempFile = tempDir & "\" & fso.GetTempName

    ' temporary powershell script file to be invoked
    powershellFile = tempFile & ".ps1"

    ' temporary file to store standard output from command
    powershellOutputFile = tempFile & ".txt"

    'if the filter is empty we use all files
    if len(filter) = 0 then
    filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    end if

    'input script
    psScript = psScript & "[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(""System.windows.forms"") | Out-Null" & vbCRLF
    psScript = psScript & "$dlg = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog" & vbCRLF
    psScript = psScript & "$dlg.initialDirectory = """ &initialDir & """" & vbCRLF
    'psScript = psScript & "$dlg.filter = ""ZIP files|*.zip|Text Documents|*.txt|Shell Scripts|*.*sh|All Files|*.*""" & vbCRLF
    psScript = psScript & "$dlg.filter = """ & filter & """" & vbCRLF
    ' filter index 4 would show all files by default
    ' filter index 1 would should zip files by default
    psScript = psScript & "$dlg.FilterIndex = 1" & vbCRLF
    psScript = psScript & "$dlg.Title = ""Select a file""" & vbCRLF
    psScript = psScript & "$dlg.ShowHelp = $True" & vbCRLF
    psScript = psScript & "$dlg.ShowDialog() | Out-Null" & vbCRLF
    psScript = psScript & "Set-Content """ &powershellOutputFile & """ $dlg.FileName" & vbCRLF
    'MsgBox psScript

    Set textFile = fso.CreateTextFile(powershellFile, True)
    textFile.WriteLine(psScript)
    textFile.Close
    Set textFile = Nothing

    ' objShell.Run (strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn]) 
    ' 0 Hide the window and activate another window.
    ' bWaitOnReturn set to TRUE - indicating script should wait for the program 
    ' to finish executing before continuing to the next statement

    Dim appCmd
    appCmd = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted &'" & powershellFile & "'"
    'MsgBox appCmd
    shell.Run appCmd, 0, TRUE

    ' open file for reading, do not create if missing, using system default format
    Set textFile = fso.OpenTextFile(powershellOutputFile, 1, 0, -2)
    ChooseFile = textFile.ReadLine
    textFile.Close
    Set textFile = Nothing
    fso.DeleteFile(powershellFile)
    fso.DeleteFile(powershellOutputFile)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is VBA but it may be enough to point you in the right direction.  The 3 declares the type of dialog you wish to open.  You can find that and more information here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865284.aspx.

```
Sub FileSelect (Multi as Boolean)
' Set Dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Set Dlg = Access.Application.FileDialog(3)
With Dlg
    .Title = "Select the file you want to open"
    .AllowMultiSelect = Multi
    If .Show = -1 Then
        txtFilePath = .InitialFileName
    Else
        Exit Function
    End If
End With

FileSelect = Dlg.SelectedItems(1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use hta, it's short and still works in win 10.
Can't filter or change the selector window caption.
You can even adapt it for use in a batch file..

```
Function SelectFile()
 Set ows=createobject("wscript.shell")
 Set oExec=ows.Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();"&_
 "new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);"&_
 "close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>"""):   
 SelectFile = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine 
 Set ows=Nothing
End Function
```